# python telethon использование по очередно нескольких telegram client избежав бана

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

Мне необходимо использовать 5 разных телеграм клиентов в день для проверки чатов каждого из них на предмет новых сообщений.Я хочу воспользоваться следующим кодом, меняя данные для каждого клиента и изменяя session_name.

```
api_id = 12345
api_hash = '0000000000abcdef0123456789abcdef'

client = TelegramClient('session_name_1', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

проверяю чаты

client.disconnect()
```

Если такая проверка будет осуществляться один раз в день, забанит ли телеграм моих клиентов? И есть ли какие-то способы избежать бана, выполнив мою задачу. Желательно, чтобы код авторизации пришлось вводить только первый раз.

Answer (score 0):

Хоть 100. Если ты не будешь рассылать спам - твои аккаунты вряд-ли заблокируют.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).